# Userscript. Тихий парсинг

Tags: javascript, userjs, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго времени суток.  
Есть возможность, с **userscript**-а, отпарсить другую страницу (не текущую) в фоново режиме?  
Спец. библиотеки или альтернативные идеи **window.open()**, или вообще любые идеи решения такой задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создавайте скрытый фрейм, в него загружайте страницу. Если страница в том же домене, куда загружен UserJS, то просто обращайтесь к `iframe.contentDocument`

```
var iframe= document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display= "none";
iframe.src= "/";
iframe.onload= function(){
    console.log(iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
};
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/3K4zM/

Comment: @ReinRaus, Да. Тот же домен, просто не хочу мозолить глаза пользователю, да и себе тоже: всплывающими окнами (оно всплывает раз в 10-15 мин, по умолчанию). Можете ссылку на гайд или рабочий пример отправить в ответ? Что б Я мог вас отблагодарить? )

Answer (score 2):

C использованием `jQuery`:

Подключаем её, если нету:

```
UserScript:
// @require     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
```

Скачиваем нужную страницу `ajax`-ом:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/dir/other-file.htm',
    dataType: "text",
    success:  function (function (data, status, xhr) {
       // парсим текст - $(data)
       // но так как html в тексте может быть невалидным
       // то завернем весь текст в div 
       var temp = $('<div/>', {html: data});
       // далее работаем как с обычным jQuery Node
       temp.find('.myclass').text(); // или each() и тд  
     } 
});
```